# Why is select in Blazor not populating selected value when a bind is done?

Tags: c#, html, user-interface, data-binding, blazor

I have a Razor component that takes a parameter of a timezone name to show the current time.
You can click to display a select dropdown of all timezones to change the timezone being displayed. The select should autopopulate with the current timezone.

```
...
<select @bind="newTimeZone" style="width:80%; margin:auto">
    @foreach(TimeZoneInfo tz in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
    {
        //Console.WriteLine($"{tz.StandardName} | {_timeZoneInfo.StandardName}");
        if (tz.StandardName == _timeZoneInfo.StandardName)
        {
           Console.WriteLine($"{tz.StandardName} | {_timeZoneInfo.StandardName}");
           <option value="@(tz.StandardName)" selected>@tz.StandardName</option>
        }else{
           Console.Write("|");
           <option value="@(tz.StandardName)">@tz.StandardName</option>
        }
    }
</select>
...
@code{
    #_timeZoneInfo is defined with the current TimeZone being displayed
    public string newTimeZone = "";
}
```

When the @bind="newTimeZone" is included, the dropdown will look like this initially:
[image]

When the @bind is removed, so the line reads:

```
<select style="width:80%; margin:auto">
```

The dropdown loads correctly with the current TimeZone:
[image]

Am I not using the @bind property correctly? I planned to use it to track the currently selected option. I see some posts talking about calling @change on every addition of .

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER**

@bind works as a two way street when implemented it seems. Not as just a get, but also a set. So it needs to be initialized with the first selected option's value.
Because of this, there is no need for the "if" statement within the loop.
Also i'm noting here that my solution does not require a null check.
Here is the updated code:

```
...
<select @bind="newTimeZone" style="width:80%; margin:auto">
    @foreach(TimeZoneInfo tz in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
    {
        //Console.WriteLine($"{tz.StandardName} | {_timeZoneInfo.StandardName}");
        <option value="@(tz.StandardName)">@tz.StandardName</option>
    }
</select>
...
@code{
    #_timeZoneInfo is defined with the current TimeZone being displayed
    public string newTimeZone = _timeZoneInfo.StandardName;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see what you're doing wrong, so here's a demo that works.  I've:

1. Switched to using the `Id` field for the timezone to identify it correctly for getting the `TimeZoneInfo`.
2. Shown how to handle a null initial value.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<select class="form-select mb-3" @bind=_tzId >
    @if( _tzId is null )
    {
        <option disabled selected value="null"> -- Select a TimeZone -- </option>
    }
    @foreach(var tz in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
    {
        <option value="@tz.Id">@tz.StandardName</option>
    }
</select>

<select class="form-select" @bind=_tzId1>
    @if (_tzId is null)
    {
        <option disabled selected value="null"> -- Select a TimeZone -- </option>
    }
    @foreach (var tz in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
    {
        <option value="@tz.Id">@tz.StandardName</option>
    }
</select>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-3 p-1">
    <pre>TZ Id : @_tzId</pre>
    <pre>TZ Nane : @_tz?.StandardName</pre>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-3 p-1">
    <pre>TZ1 Id : @_tzId1</pre>
    <pre>TZ1 Nane : @_tz1?.StandardName</pre>
</div>
@code {
    private string? _tzId;
    private string? _tzId1 = "Pacific Standard Time";

    private TimeZoneInfo? _tz => _tzId is null ? null: TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(_tzId);
    private TimeZoneInfo? _tz1 => _tzId1 is null ? null : TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(_tzId1);
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Your answer actually helped me realize what was going on!
There's 2 main things:
1) @ bind is a two way street so it needs to be initialized to the first selected option
2) Since @ bind handles the select there is actually no need for the "if" statement in the loop!